# How to center a CSS Hexagon

Tags: css, shapes, css-shapes

Not sure how to center this hexagon, setting margin: auto; doesn't effect the whole shape. Grateful if anyone could help, thanks in advance.

```
.hexagon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 173.21px;
    background-color: #fff;
}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {

    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-left: 150px solid transparent;
    border-right: 150px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
      bottom: 100%;
      border-bottom: 86.60px solid #fff;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
}

.hexagon:after {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      width: 0;
      border-top: 86.60px solid #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`margin:auto` won't work if you have absolutely positioned divs so to center the hexagon, you have to add `top:50%`, `left:50%` and `margin: -86.6px 0 0 -150px`. The -86.6px is half the height of your hexagon and -150px is the half of the width. Also you have to make its parent position relative with a height of 100%.

**HTML**

```
<div class="hexagon"></div>
```

**CSS**

```
html,body{
    background-color:#333;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    position:relative;
}

.hexagon {
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin: -86.6px 0 0 -150px ;
}
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1ojkr88s/1/)

Comment: `margin:auto won't work if you have absolutely positioned divs` ... Just for reference, it does, actually, if you also use `left` and `right`.

Answer (score 0):

If you just mean centering horizontally, you could do this: http://codepen.io/pageaffairs/pen/fxoHp

```
.hexagon {left: 0; right: 0; margin: auto;}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can put it into another div which has margin:auto. see code here http://jsfiddle.net/oswxj9c5/

html:

```
<div class="parent">
    <article>
<div class="hexagon">
</div>
    </article>
</div>
```

css:

```
.parent {
    position:relative;
    background:blue;
    width:900px;
    height:500px;
    margin:auto;
}

article {
    margin:auto;

    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    background:transparent;
}

.hexagon {
    position: absolute;
    width: 300px; 
    height: 173.21px;
    background-color: red;
    top:150px;
    margin:auto;

}

.hexagon:before,
.hexagon:after {

    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-left: 150px solid transparent;
    border-right: 150px solid transparent;
}

.hexagon:before {
      bottom: 100%;
      border-bottom: 86.60px solid red;
      position: absolute;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
}

.hexagon:after {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      width: 0;
      border-top: 86.60px solid red;
}
```